Should I expect a speed increase if I change from aluminum to copper wire for VDSL2?
I've a VDSL2 service, over my existing telephone line, the line is almost 15 to 20 meters long from the demarc to my house, with an extra 10 run inside the house to the modem, this were the stats before cutting ~5 meters of the extra 10 inside the house:

And a:

Ad you can see there's a slight increase of the signal to noise ratio, and a slight decrease of attenuation, but that could also be due to a better termination of the cable after cutting the part I cut.
Regardless, that cable is aluminum, Cat3 I think or twisted telephone cable "2 inner wires", my service is allows up to 150mbs.
Should I expect a decent increase of speed using copper, or given my stats "attenuation in particular" could the main contributor be the connection from the demarc to the "central office." I was thinking of using an outdoor Cat6a cable using the two inner wires and the two next to them since I've two phone lines.
Edit:

This just happened today out of the blue, for the past year or so the max possible rate never went above 30k, now it's 40k, what could cause this?

The relatively short length of cable inside your house is unlikely to have any significant effect on your signal compared to the relatively long length from your local telephone cabinet.

@Mokubai even with the difference in impedance at the demarc?

@Gantendo nope, of course not

Inside your home for such a short length of cable there is likely to be maybe an ohm of difference in cable impedance. Certainly not enough to care about compared to the street cabling. As far as the telecoms cabinet is concerned you've done nearly nothing to the stretch of cable to your modem. Yes, you may have made a minor improvement (your peak downstream speed is now 84533kbps instead of 83862kbps) but the difference is almost within the same kind of ballpark you might expect if you just happened to reset your router on a day with less solar activity, or different phase of the moon.

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/copper-aluminum-conductor-resistance-d_1877.html suggests that for 1000ft of cabling copper has a resistance of 23 ohms while aluminium is at 35 ohms. Doing the math that comes down to 0.076 ohms per meter for copper for a resistance of 2.3ohms for your 30 meter run. If that entire 30m run was aluminium you get 0.116 ohms per meter or 3.5 ohms for a 30 meter run. You might maybe see a difference of 1.2 ohms for the length of cable you have control over and that is nearly no change whatsoever. You aren't going to see any "game changing" difference.

@Mokubai but I'm asking about completely replacing the cable from the demarc, to my modem, & the difference of electrical properties between it & the wire from the centeral to demarc core, to the wire from demarc to house I've rn which is pure aluminum, I thought this is also why jacks are always pure copper?

@Mokubai I actually don't think I'm getting the speed I should be getting, the signal is VDSL2, & measuring the line distance between the central and demarc it's 180 m, so even if we assume double the distance of wiring 360m, I should be getting more than 100mbs, no?

Since you're considering replacing the wiring, you must have access to the demarc box. Rather than speculate or ask the Internet, why not perform a quick but informative experiment by connecting the modem right at the demac box?

"I should be getting more than 100mbs, no?" - What speed are you actually paying for?

@sawdust 150/50, & I don't have access to the demarc myself, but I can get the ISP technician to change wires for me as I did before

check my edit, any explanation, could this mean that the ISP are limiting the signal strength or something

More important than DC resistance for high-speed cable is it's AC impedance (and proper termination) and lack of internal discontinuities.
One can check those qualities with a time domain reflectometer. If you do not have that pricey piece of kit, perhaps you local cable service might let you borrow theirs... or not.
Since it is unlikely you are going to get such a determination of the existing cable condition, you have a few choices. Here are two:

Blindly replace existing cabling with new, with absolutely no reason to think you'll be better off. Test the speed after the switch, and change back to the old cable, if the new is actually slower.
Wait until you switch to fiber or other high speed connection.


sorry if this is a stupid question, but wouldn't the change from copper to aluminum, twice, once at the demarc, and another at the termination rj11 be considered an "internal discontinuity"?

No, impedance discontinuity has nothing to do with conductor material. It is derived from diameter of wires, thickness and dielectric constant of insulation, wire spacing, twist pitch, etc.
